# Why does UINavigationBarAppearance have an init(idiom:) initializer?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios13

If I create a UINavigationBarAppearance like this...

```
let app = UINavigationBarAppearance(idiom: .pad)
```

...and configure it with a background color and set my navigation bar's `standardAppearance` to it, I see the color even on an iPhone.

So why does this initializer exist? What distinction are we drawing here?

Comment: It does seem odd. The `UIBarAppearance.init()` calls `UIBarAppearance(idiom:)` with the proper idiom. And even if you call `UIBarAppearance(idiom:)` with the wrong idiom (the case with the code in your question), the documentation clearly states *"If you specify an idiom that doesn't make sense for the current device, this method adjusts the idiom to an appropriate value."* So yes, why bother with this specific `init` since the idiom is basically ignored and the current idiom is forced. That can be done in the `init()` initializer.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom initializer primarily exists as a stop gap should it make sense later and be needed (for various reasons its easier to have this earlier than later). In general, and at this time, no one should have a need to call it.